# REGEX: match and exec returns different results

Tags: javascript, regex

```
let regexp = /Rim.*?vert\s(\d*)cm/g
let content = "BEONE SPS SPIRIT, 2012y.b.,26 Rim - BEONE aluminium, vert 51cm «L»,ЕТТ600mm, 835 37 38"
```

After executing `content.match(regexp)`, i got:

```
["Rim - BEONE aluminium, vert 51cm"]
```

So, i expected it'll return matched group (51) as a second array element.

But when i'm using `regexp.exec(content)`, everything seems to be OK:

```
["Rim - BEONE aluminium, vert 51cm", "51"]
```

Why there is such a difference?

What is wrong with my code\regexp so it returns different results?

Comment: If you drop the `g` modifier, you'll get the same result with `match`. I suppose it knows then that there can be no more matches, so it provides the captured group. Not exactly sure, but probably something like that.

Comment: @squint but the Group is what is inside the rounded brakets, right?

Comment: Yes. But if the regex is global, and can therefore potentially find multiple matches, it could be very confusing if it gave the full string plus the subgroup matches. Where does one start and the next end?

Comment: Simply consult [the documentation for `String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match): "If the regular expression does not include the g flag, returns the same result as RegExp.exec() [...] If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects. Captured groups are not returned."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in [String.prototype.match() MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> if you want to obtain capture groups and the global flag is set, you
>   need to use [RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) instead.

So, to obtain the same result with `String.prototype.match()`, remove the `g` flag from the regular expression:

```js
let regexp = /Rim.*?vert\s(\d*)cm/ //<-- Removed the "g" flag.
let content = "BEONE SPS SPIRIT, 2012y.b.,26 Rim - BEONE aluminium, vert 51cm «L»,ЕТТ600mm, 835 37 38";

let resultMatch = content.match(regexp);
console.log('result with match:', resultMatch);

let resultExec = regexp.exec(content);
console.log('result with exec:', resultExec);
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth mentioning that if the outcome of string.match() and regex.exec() are the same then regex.exec() will take somewhere **much** more time (between x2 to x30) then string.match():

In such cases, use regex.exec() only when you need a global regex (to execute more than once).